# Doubling of a verb

Tags: verbs, word-usage, reduplication

When a relative clause modifies a noun it often leads to a construction with two verbs in a row. I was wondering whether repeating the same verb is acceptable enough in such situation, as with the verb "hit" in the sentence below:

The ball you hit hit me.

Comment: I wanted to know whether speakers might feel the repetition of the verb as awkward, inelegant, unclear.. The sentence is grammatical, of course. Google didn't turn up any relevant results for "hit hit",which was why I asked this question in the first place (I've tried a couple of other verbs and also no results). It might be interesting to learn why is that so,  however, I'm happy with the answers I got ( Peter Shor's was rather a succinct one true, but with his reputation on the forum that will do :)

Comment: I think that a really fluent speaker would either avoid the jarring juxtaposition (this looks like something out of a well-intentioned but unrealistic school grammar textbook), or give an intended awkward pause and  rueful smile-or-is-it, in recognition of thye awkwardness: "The ball you hit ... _hit me_." // This is possibly a near-enough-duplicate of the 'is-is' construction (qv).

Comment: Thank you Edwin! That is precisely what I wanted to know:) This sentence comes from a university entrance test.

Comment: I've suggested a novel definite article. Hmm, typos aside, I remember using 'All this is, is another way of saying ...' in a maths lesson once. The head of English popped in (we had observation windows) and said "Ah, the 'is-is' construction!" // With other pairings, there would be intonation choices to avoid a wooden ' ... hit hit ...',  '... saw saw ...' etc. There are avoidance strategies, like 'The old lady I noticed, herself noticed the strange-looking vehicle in the field' (comma considered acceptable there [by many] to aid parsing).

Comment: The verb "avoid" came to mind when I was asking this question :) I actually wanted to ask "Do you feel like avoiding using the same verb twice in a row, in spite of the obvious grammaticality of the sentence?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your sentence is:

> [Det] [NP] [V] [PN]
>
> [The] [ball you hit] [hit] [me].

The noun phrase "ball you hit" is just as good as "ball" by itself in your sentence.

> The ball hit me.
>
> Which ball? The red ball or the ball I hit?
>
> The ball you hit, not the red ball. The ball you hit hit me. The red ball didn't hit me.

It doesn't matter that the last word of the noun phrase is "hit" and that the main verb is also "hit".

Comment: Thank you Dennis! Of course, I am aware that the construction is grammatically possible, as you explained above, I just thought that the repetition of the verb  may sound awkward.

Comment: There are other sentences with the same construction that can't be easily reworded: "The one he had had was the best." "The woman he saw saw him do it." "The boy that the girl likes likes her too." ad nauseum.